# Sort list by types

Tags: code-golf

## Rules

You will receive as input a list that contains integers and strings. Your task is to move all of the strings to the end of the list and all of the integers to the beginning of the list.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the answer with the least number of bytes wins.

Comment: Do the integers and strings need to stay in the original order relative to other elements of the same type?

Comment: @xnor No. The order may be destroyed.

Comment: May the output list have extra items in it? For example, given `[1,"a",2,"b"]` could we output `[1,2,None,"a",None,"b"]`?

Comment: @sugarfi No. The task is to sort without adding anything.

Comment: What do you do for a language that doesn't have integers except as strings of ASCII digits?

Comment: Does it have to be an integer or can it be a string of digits? If so, what about strings with digits in them?

Comment: @Neil I'm new to code-golf so I didn't know that there're some languages.

Comment: @S.S. Anne If your golf language has no integers you can use a digit string.

Comment: What if it has no combined lists of integers and strings?

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda l:l.sort(key=dir)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKkevOL@oRCM7tdI2JbNI83@OrUK0UqKSjoKhjoJSEpA2AtLJQNoYSBsCaSUjEGGsFMuVppGjyVVQlJlXAmT8BwA)

Sorts in place, modifying the input list. It so happens that the `dir` of a number is smaller than that of a string because the `__abs__` method that numbers have comes alphabetically first.

```python
>> dir(1)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', ...]
>> dir('a')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', ...]
```

The only built-in to use as a key that would be shorter than `dir` is `id`, but it seems to puts strings before numbers, and I don't know if its behavior is consistent.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 6 bytes

```python
sorted
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzvzi/qCQ15X@OrUK0UqKSjoKhjoJSEpA2AtLJQNoYSBsCaSUjEGGsFMtVUJSZV6KQppGj@R8A)

Python 2 allows comparing different types, and conveniently numbers come before strings.

Comment: @Victor The 05AB1E solution should win because it was posted first and is shortest, unless this is [popularity-contest] in which case it is off-topic.

Comment: @S.S Anne This code-golf question was inspired by a similar question on StackOverflow in Russian about python. So I'm interested mostly in python solutions but all other answers are interesting to me as well. Ok, I'll accept 05AB1E.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Thank you for playing by the rules :)

Comment: @S.S.Anne I thought to accept an answer does not mean anything on this site but now I understood ;) Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

05AB1E does this *exactly* as specified.

```
{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@v//aEMdpUQlHSMdYx2lJCUdpWSlWAA)

[Or, verify all test cases (so far)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9u6//q/7X/o6MNdZQSlXSMdIx1lJKUdJSSlWJ14GJAkdhYAA)

## Explanation

Even if the answer is a one-byte answer, I still feel like typing the explanation.

```
Implicit input as a list
{ Sort the list (numbers go before the strings)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 1 byte

```apl
∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HH8v9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/g/kPYK9vdTSFOAstSjDXWUEpV0jHSMdZSSlHSUkpVi1bnwKAMqilUHAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 4 bytes

```
Sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277Pzi/qOR/QFFmXomCQ3p0taGOUqKSjpGOUpJSbez//wA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>!b.big-!a.big)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcVBCoAgEADAr6SnFUywzvqR6LBrJUW4kdH3N5vLHPhiTfd@PX3hZZUtCIaIrvL9AKAlE6IiR3vuFf4ZSVwqn6s7OcMGk/badt52mtpDO7XH2Rj5AA)

#### How?

The deprecated but still widely supported method [`.big()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/big) is defined for Strings and undefined for Numbers. Hence the sorting criterion `!b.big-!a.big` which is either \$-1\$, \$0\$ or \$1\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.sort_by &:methods}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOkevOL@oJD6pUkHNKje1JCM/pbj2f4FCWnS0UqKSjoKhjoJSEpA2AtLJQNoYSBsCaSUjEGGsFBv7HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
L.sort(key=lambda x:str(type(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7vo2CrEK2UqKSjYKijoJQEpI2AdDKQNo7976NXnF9UopGdWmmbk5iblJKoUGFVXFKkUVJZkKpRoamp@b@gKDOvRMNH8z8A)

And in fact this is how I'd write it in live code too, probably...

Comment: Why not `L.sort(key=lambda x:str(type(x)))`?

Comment: Ah yeah, that space is unnecessary indeed.

Comment: It's a common output that higher-rep people are often outgolfed by lower-rep people ...

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 23 bytes

```
func[x][reverse sort x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxDoAgDAXQ3VP89A5q4jFcm07QJixgChJuX33Lc81xa2bZ7Ap7a@Il7DrVu6I3H1gSj5c6YGBqVQlkZf7tOA9QallJ4gM)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```java
L->{L.sort((i,j)->i==i.toString()?1:-1);}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

Input as a `List` of `Object`s, with `String` and `Integer` items.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVLLbsIwELzzFas9OYpjNVD1wFO9p7QSR9qDCQY5DTGKFyqK@PbUcUKFCq16SWTPY2c2yeReRtnyvUpzaS08SV0cOwC6IFWuZKpgWh8B9kYvIWWZo4sd6Vwk2tLweZGplMaQBAPHOnXcw5IkncIUChhBlUTjYyKsKYkxzbMgGuvRSAsyMyp1sWbBJO5HcTA4VYNavN0tciduPfzMjUvEGvb8DWTQxCFlicX8nmMXOabIH3yCFkCJPOa4QN71YI9jjA21h1dR/Riva@oIIb7n/NI3dwdXr1AfF4zHspQHTxuzH7dWSFsjTAZtzm2piA4vrhax2q29nh0sqY0wOxJbj2EfsMUKkV5S/@mQF@x240v9HzXbRVwHm59zrUzJ3A3o0d0A9LAWCas/lZsLrRqgsQTjtuYJa0VMtwY33Jlxv6BLW6TKrKD5/BPAV8TQhPUL@mACCIGFoYYhXAwFx@M1jm943vbJL@BUfQE)

**Explanation:**

```java
L->{                    // Method with Object-List parameter and no return-type
  L.sort(               //  Sort the List by:
    (i,j)->             //   For every pair of items `i,j`:
      i==i.toString()?  //    If `i` is a String (by checking whether `i` and the builtin
                        //    String-conversion of `i` reference the same instance):
       1                //     Put it after item `j`
      :                 //    Else:
       -1);}            //     Put it before item `j`
```

Comment: `i==i.toString()?1:-1` saves 2 bytes. (Obviously, this can only ever be true for `String` objects, and it's also fortunately trivially true for all `String` objects.)

Comment: @Neil Ah, very smart, thanks! This is only the second time I use Java's referencing on Strings as an advantage with codegolfing. :) (The first was once with `s==s.trim()` to check whether a String didn't contained any trailing and/or leading white-spaces.)

Answer (score 2):

## [<s>Perl 6</s> Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

-1 thanks to Jo King.

```perl6
*.sort(*~~Str)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7BCsIwGIPve4qAYHWMoh4EGT6AZ4/iobpMh2s3@v9DvPjqs/UQEsJHyMjY72f/wbLFcS6tDFFX5fd71rie66JYwI4JQSeYhA2ejIQO8O5FdAo66Rhzo@x7vJ/UhIA9PYMKXMLD5G@MgiFCNHbhIRYnTZPBKALZsLGFuA/a1cW4291UOBwqmG0KpmGbbZfLCttN1ua6/r@q5x8)

This is an anonymous WhateverCode function nested within another. I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY7BCsIwGIPve4qAYHWMoh4EGT6AZ4/iobpMh2s3@v9DvPjqs/UQEsJHyMjY72f/wbLFcS6tDFFX5fd71rie66JYwI4JQSeYhA2ejIQO8O5FdAo66Rhzo@x7vJ/UhIA9PYMKXMLD5G@MgiFCNHbhIRYnTZPBKALZsLGFuA/a1cW4291UOBwqmG0KpmGbbZfLCttN1ua6/r@q5x8) with `*~~Str`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
lambda x:[*filter(lambda _:type(_)==int,x)]+[*filter(lambda _:type(_)==str,x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaHCKlorLTOnJLVIAyoSb1VSWZCqEa9pa5uZV6JToRmrjUdJcUkRSMn//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ñy
```

[Test it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8Xk&input=WyJhIiwiYiIsImMiLCIxIiwxLCIyIiwyLCIzIiwzXQotUQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 20 bytes

```php
fn(&$a)=>sort($a,2);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCgIxEET7/YphWSSBbTzLGP2QI0g8PHLNXUjSid8eY2U3894wOeV@veeUQSQbPGaaz8qRddKL8pOVFw76hwMFCm6sq@/rbk4Srb/VozQjUSfr@nDrUV5xSQbjMlZIg8WbAKlGmoUbMZdtb4/y644@6F8)

Comment: From the question `Your task is to move all strings...`, there is no output or function needed, and from what I see for example from the 05AB1E's answer, isn't `sort($t,2);` enough?

Comment: @Kaddath Unless otherwise specified, default rules require all submissions to be full programs or functions.

Comment: @Neil OK that's noted, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 36 bytes

```bash
p=egrep\ ^-?[0-9]+$
tee a|$p
$p -v<a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8A2Nb0otSBGIU7XPtpA1zJWW4WrJDVVIbFGpYBLpUBBt8wm8f9/U2MTrsSkZK5EUy4uy2KuikqjbC5dY0MDLkMjEwA)

A value is considered to be an integer if: (1) the first character is either a digit or a minus sign; (2) any other characters are all digits; and (3) at least one digit is present.  Any value that is not an integer is considered to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 26 bytes

```r
function(L)sort(unlist(L))
```

Straightforward: `unlist` then `sort` the list `L`. Works because digits sort before alphabetic letters, be them upper or lower case.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P600L7kkMz9Pw0ezOL@oRKM0LyezuATI0/z/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 117 bytes

```c
f(a,l,p,c)struct{int*s,i;}*a,*p;{for(c=l,p=a;c--;p++)p->s?:printf("%d ",p->i);for(;l--;a++)a->s&&printf("%s ",a->s);}
```

C does not have lists of combined strings and integers so instead I use an array of structures; if the string is `NULL` (which a real string never will be), then print the integer instead. Of course, go over the list an print the integers first, then the strings.

Stable sort.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBLTsMwEAbgfU4xskRlpxORtjtGgYNUXRi3AUttYtkOC6KcPYyTAg3UG3t@f36a4s2YcaylxjM6NCpE35nY2ybmAS0NucbcUV@3XpqKSaXJFAW59Vq54jm8PDnPtpbi4QgCObKKEqYzK81Ks1qtflRglSJFwzifBbZxXQxZnwE386495IGmgteApWygLEvDi7aN/GjtUV3xYoNrtz9ANU3OZBoJLRDKAX@TEmFzW4vXO2K7EOaO2C3E5q8Q23/J7iZJ70p9LeerIwT7eWq/S/W4KPflQan5X/wpdr6Bkr9m/AI)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 35 bytes

Decimals will be placed in the integer section

```sql
DECLARE @ table(a varchar(99))
INSERT @ values('1'),('a'),('abc'),('1'),('d'),('84753')

SELECT*FROM @ ORDER BY-isnumeric(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 2 bytes

```
><
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@tZKikoGBkrKBkpKSglJiUrKRgqGBc@9/O5v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
o$dir(N)
```

I don't know what it is about python eval that makes me feel like I'm bending the rules, but I like it :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P18lJbNIw0/z//9oQx2lgABndyUdBUMTIx0FJc8S9WKF5PycFIXMPIWM1KJUBSsNpdh/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 24 bytes

```
O$^m`^(-?[0-9]+$)?.*$
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fXyUuNyFOQ9c@2kDXMlZbRdNeT0uFS8Xw//9ELkOuJC4DrmQuXUMA) Explanation:

```
m`^(-?[0-9]+$)?.*$
```

Match each line, capturing it if it's an integer.

```
O$
$1
```

Sort the matches by the captured integer, as a string. This sorts non-integers to the beginning as nothing was captured which results in the empty string in the substitution.

```
^
```

Reverse the list after sorting.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｆ²ΦＥθ⭆¹κ⁼ι⁼κ§θλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0hTIaAoM69Ewy0zpyS1SMM3sUCjUEchuAQomA7iGOooZGtq6ii4FpYm5hRrZMJZ2ToKjiWeeSmpFSANOZogYP3/f3S0UqKSjgJQm1ISkDYA0slAWtcwNva/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²
```

Make two passes over the input items.

```
Ｅθ⭆¹κ
```

Stringify all the input items...

```
Φ...⁼ι⁼κ§θλ
```

... and filter on those elements that are not or are unchanged under stringification respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 320 Bytes

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /P S=Str:
FOR %%B IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) DO (
IF "!L!"=="" (Set L=!S:%%B= !) Else (Set L=!L:%%B= !)
)
FOR %%C IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) DO (
IF "!R!"=="" (Set R=!S:%%C= !) Else (Set R=!R:%%C= !)
)
Set S=%L: =%%R: =%
ECHO(%S%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 41 bytes

Expects and returns a `List<Any>`. The order of ints and strings in the returned list should be stable.

```
{it.partition{it is Int}.let{(a,b)->a+b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX3/YphVglOC742YgMuBcFvSNXAYJyWdhSk5Ntj24V3czmLc56tRpb88RHCAcyFBz2e5OsslA7@BHUeWavO98rKrUwAPMBZNFXxoaPx1NjS@VWTUg5vgZdnMRbGAqbN8TiloF7uGpamWdOG0CNhg7QlvCHtaE94R7tYXc@iJphZsbZIkH8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
^'#s
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

```
^'#s # Expects the list as input
^'   # Sort the input using the following function as a key:
  #s # Is string?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```factor
[ [ real? 0 1 ? ] sort-with ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxCsJAEAXQPqf4TK8oooIWKcXGJliFFEuYJIPrbBgnBBHPvgYP8F4XWk@W79X1djnhwaYc8Qw@4JXMRXuMxu7v0UQd56L4YAvyORF2oC5NRtjjgCOIpR@cQCrKhG@uUcM4xBKbxZRo/uVqliVvchtixDr/AA)

Is it a real number? Then sort it as though it were 0. Otherwise, sort it as though it were 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊏⍏.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAg4oqP4o2PLgoKZiB7ImFiYyIgMTUgImRlZiIgMSAyfQo=)

This is the default behavior of sorting a boxed list in Uiua.

```
⊏⍏.
  .  # duplicate
 ⍏   # rise (grade up)
⊏    # select
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 75 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVLRSsMwFAUf9xWXPCXaDreJSF0He1ZBEPGhlpF17ZYxU0nipI5-iS--6ItfNL_Gmybb3MBCc5N7zs09ycn7l874gve-ExLK8pUrSdL1aTme55mBGy4krFqtFsCSL0BG9FpokwxllcaD7ZRB_PliivBifTVq61KZB2Fmq4zrnIrozighp8E8QiaLB91-59IjmMC0wy0ycAiMmnnttvw5YgCTvIAnlEK5muoIhkrxKnGFKYvgXgoDMeoE_EyuDe0EcBYA6RIcMhzO2Q4jHBNIIGOMXU_oYeyQTUmPWH5tj21bN2Uc-8rq-LDdkitY4EVggrdNae-kyT-r3JjqFiUaanHms3ZNIiBu7SvlHuXfwoWke7oOqRHsLDmQ6Rsnvm9RKqAC-mGjoC3kRGS5Zp7szC6x2KJUMJ8t0QSTzbYsgMYvdMR5AfFg0-iREDgBjb-dsv2C0Y5YbqDaR1E0wpwuLd5yCKHDNtsGfqv676FS75Z_MR8fLv4C)

```scala
_.sortWith{case(i:String,j:Any)=>2<1;case(i:Any,j:String)=>2>1;case _=>2>1}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVO9TsMwEB7YOvAMJ08JJJHaIoQiisReEBJCDKGqXNcproKNbLeooDwJCwssvBFPw9lxaFOJIT777vvuJ5_9_mUYrejwuyCpVC9USzL5-FzZMj37OThUsyVnFq6okPDWA7CaCgvXfg8w5yWwaJzDWBhbXMrNJN7ZI6Tu4bKmFcgcSSPoYmF0ERKNM6O0vRf2MTgAGDUcIpHDrdVCLhJY5oAsTyppZfg-DoMe1OA9zupVBzbtOOu2QTfGE04YUb0wmEhruimaNG6gO4kjj0Jjlhsb9RM4SYAMCC4Ml9N4GyMUHQggM7SDABii7ZOWMiTxbmlPo36Ao_1ya6qhwh-GDppZ5f6d9z9rbu3mBlu0kYvHwevOJAfSnANTZqwD-pdayajT2T60K3Sn0VC6CJVLpVEUOE99D5mQc8G4if_UdXdCIdlFIxEHr0IZLNvegSCbaUV18oVCD4TAMRj83DbuEqZboGpDdbCi9I01fRnxyiGFftymTUKqeneoSdCrbp5FeB0fwf4C)

```scala
object Main {
  trait N {
    def c(L: List[Any]): List[Any]
  }

  val n: N = (L: List[Any]) => {
    L.sortWith {
      case (i: String, j: Any) => false
      case (i: Any, j: String) => true
      case _ => true
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    test(1, 4, "2", "c", 6)
    test("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3, "1", "2", "3")
  }

  def test(a: Any*): Unit = {
    var list = a.toList
    prettyPrint(list)
    print(": ")
    list = n.c(list)
    prettyPrint(list)
    println()
  }

  def prettyPrint(list: List[Any]): Unit = {
    print("[")
    for (i <- list.indices) {
      val o = list(i)
      o match {
        case s: String => print("\"" + s + "\"")
        case _ => print(o)
      }
      if (i < list.size - 1) print(",")
    }
    print("]")
  }
}
```